# Raspberry Pi spidev.h SPI Communication

Tags: c, communication, raspberry-pi, spi

I try to establish a spi communication from RPi (Master) to an EtherCAT Device (Slave).

The transfer of data got a scheme.

I have to transfer 2 bytes which address registers and the following bytes transfer data till a chip select terminates the communication.

This is my created attempt. With cs_change, i can tell my spi communication to deselect Chip Select before the next transfer starts.

```
char transfer(UINT8 data, char last)
{
char last_transfer = last;
int ret;
uint8_t tx[] = { data };
uint8_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)] = { };

struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
        .cs_change = 0,
    };

if (last_transfer)
    tr.cs_change = 1;

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
if (ret < 1)
    printf("can't send spi message");

return rx[tr.len-1];
}
```

First problem:
I think it is too late to deselect Chip Select first at new transfer.
So my first question: Is there another way to control my Chip Select signal, maybe another library i can use?!

Second problem:
I want to read from spi without writing on it, how can i realise that ( with a simple read(fd...) ?!)

I hope you guys can support me :)

Answer (score 0):

Now this is spidev_test.c application you are referring to. The implementation seems to work as slave SPI device would be deselected after your last transfer. It stays selected until after the last transfer in a message.
Each SPI device is deselected when it's not in active use, allowing other drivers to talk to other devices as may be your SPI bus is shared among other slave SPI devices.
And moreover you are going for full-duplex.
Standard read() operation is obviously only half-duplex.
So whenever your SPI slave device wants to send data to the SPI controller(Master), then it must have some interrupt mechanism so that your driver/app can set the SPI controller to "SPI_IOC_RD_MODE" and can make "SPI_IOC_MESSAGE" providing only rx_buf OR you can go for only simple read() operation as the transfer would be half_duplex after setting the SPI controller to read mode. -Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPI_NO_CS mode and toggle the CS pins as GPIO using the wiringPi library... (from http://wiringpi.com/ )